# Docker fails to copy nginx conf

Tags: docker, nginx

I have Dockerfile to deploy my frontend, which is in react.
This is what I have in my dockerfile.

```
  # Stage 1
FROM node:8 as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When I run `$ docker build . -t frontend`
I am getting an error on step 8, which fails to copy the nginx.conf

```
Step 8/10 : COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fef4deafd532bb0aa7eaea50ae25412e93f7972eab3a0579fe494de444d86a0b/merged/app/build: no such file or directory
```

But the nginx conf file exists, and I don't understand what's going on there, can somebody enlighten me what's going on?
http://prntscr.com/l2to47 This is my project structure, which clearly says there are nginx.conf but Docker can't find it.

Comment: @Shiju it's possible to have multiple FROM statements now, it's a new docker feature called [docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't fail to copy the `nginx.conf` file, it fails to find the data generated during the `react-build` stage.

I had the same problem once, that I solved changing the `WORKDIR` directory, since the original one was exposed as `VOLUME` (and it seems like it doesn't work using multi-stage builds). Try with a different one, e.g.:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:8 as react-build
WORKDIR /builddir
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /builddir/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And see if it solves the problem.